# Return full list of months between start and end dates

Tags: sql, teradata

I need a way to return a LIST of months, not the number of months between the start and end of a period, and can't find a solution.

For example, if a record shows that a contract period starts on 2017-04-12 and ends on 2018-04-22, I need to return a full list of months that covers. So the output would look like this:

```
Months_active  
2017-04  
2017-05  
2017-06  
2017-07  
....  
2018-03  
2018-04
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try something like this for selecting disticnt month SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%M)
FROM table_name where date> start and date< end;      I didn't check this. please correct any syntax mistake

Comment: How is your data stored?

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice extension for creating time series in Teradata:

```
SELECT To_Char(Begin(pd),'yyyy-mm') -- this extracts the year/month
FROM myTbable
-- this create one row for each month in the date range
EXPAND ON PERIOD(Trunc(start_date,'mon'), Last_Day(end_date)+1) AS pd BY ANCHOR Month_Begin
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. Thank you for the quick reply.